# RegEx to match sets of literal strings along with value ranges

Tags: regex

Utter RegEx noob here with a project involving RegEx I need to modify.  Has been a blast learning all of this.

I need to search for/verify a set of vales that start with one of two string combinations (NC or KH) and a variable numeric list—unique to each string prefix.  NC01-NC13 or KH01-11.

I have been able to pull off the first common "chunk" of this with:

```
^(NC|KH)0[1-9]$
```

to verify NC01-NC09 or KH01-KH09.  The next part is completely throwing me—needing to change the leading character of the two-digit character to a 1 vs a 0, and restricting the range to 0–3 for NC and 0–1 for KH.

I have found references abound for selecting between two strings (where I got the (NC|KH) from), but nothing as detailed as how to restrict following values based on the found text.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated, as well as any great references/books/tutorials to RegEx (currently using Regular-Expressions.info).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to just separate the two case altogether.

```
((NC(0\d|1[0-3])|(KH(0\d|1[01])))
```

You might want to turn some of those internal capturing groups into non capturing groups, but that make the regex a little hard to read.

Edit:  You might also be able to do this with positive lookbehind.
Edit: Here's a regex using lookbehind.  It's a lot messier, and not really necessary here, but hopefully demonstrates the utility:

```
(KH|NC)(0\d|(?<=KH)(1[01])|(?<=NC)(1[0-3]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Sticking with your original idea of options for `NC` or `KH`, do the same for the numbers, try this:

```
^(NC|KH)(0[1-9]|1[0-3])$
```

Hope that makes sense

**EDIT:**

Based upon @Patrick's comment below, and sticking with this original answer, you could use this (although I bet there's a better way):

```
^(NC|KH)(0[1-9]|1[0-1])|(NC1[2-3])$
```

Comment: But this matches `KH13`, which is not in the pattern.

Comment: Darn it, missed that... Bad answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Updated to account for it. Thanks!

Comment: Your `KH1[2-3]` at the end should be `NC1[2-3]`

Comment: Thanks again @PatrickHaugh! - Your solution is nicer, though.

Comment: Thanks much, all, for your responses.  New to this - thought I would get emails when answers appeared, but didn't see any.  I ended up using the online tool RegExPal to test different patterns until they all worked.  I ended up with:  ^((NC0[1-9]|CN1[0-3])|(KH0[1-9]|KH1[0-1]))$ .  I'm guessing this is a little more complicated than necessary - but it seems to work(?)